# Are there any alternatives to phpQuery with WebBrowser plugin?

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, web-scraping

I am looging for any (PHP) alternatives to phpQuery which also mimic behaviors of web browser (like phpQuery's WebBrowser plugin). I like phpQuery, but it was last updated in May 2009.
Any suggests?

Comment: Most popular now a days is https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

Answer (score 2):

You could try PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

These examples are from the online manual http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

```
$ret = $html->find('#foo');

// Find all element which class=foo
$ret = $html->find('.foo');

// Find all anchors and images
$ret = $html->find('a, img');

// Find all anchors and images with the "title" attribute
$ret = $html->find('a[title], img[title]');
```